# ColorBox integration in Magento

Tags: magento, colorbox

I want to add [ColorBox jQuery](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) in my Magento website. Is there an specific method for this?
Or do I have to make the changes in .phtml files?

Comment: You can make things simpler for yourself by choosing a Prototype based solution instead, such as the original [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new javascript library on all your pages use layouts. Create new layout file yourmodule.xml and put there code

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/colorbox.js</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>js/colorbox.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: To add several lines of code to your post, don't use backticks. Just indent the code by four spaces and it will display with proper linebreaks, etc.